# How to increase linespread in titletoc?

Tags: titletoc

I was using titletoc to include 'CHAPTER' in the table of contents. But for long chapter titles, the linespread became uneven (see figure).

[image: long chapter title]

This has disrupted the double spacing format using `\linespred{2}` that I have applied and wanted to be applied. The middle line seems inappropriate spaced. This is the code for titletoc that I have applied.

```
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\vspace{10pt}}{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\chaptername} \ \thecontentslabel\quad}{}{\hfill\contentspage}
```

How can I fix the linespread?